# Is there anything like .NET DataView/ DataSet for Java, where I can snapshot some data and then perform queries on it?

Tags: java, xml, data-structures, dataset, dataview

**Context**

In our application, we *snapshot* data from a database using a query that is entered by a super user, and then we save the data from that snapshotting using XML. If I was using .NET, I would use a DataSet (+ DataTables) and DataViews, which are pretty good for that purpose. But I am in the Java world, and my impulse choice was to store the snapshotted data using XML (this can be easily changed at this phase of the project).

**Question 1**

Is there anything that allows you to snapshot data without having to create its structure first for the Java platform, like a DataSet would do for .NET, and that would allow to perform queries on that data later? I thought about storing it in the database or using Apache Lucene, but for both approaches I would have to manage the database structure, which I would prefer not doing.

**Question 2**

Supposed you have the following XML:

```
<data>
<record>
   <user>ravi</user>
   <age>32</age>
   <city>calgary</city>
</record>
<record>
   <user>spiderman</user>
   <age>68</age>
   <city>new york</city>
</record>
</data>
```

And, on that data, I would execute the following query:

```
age > 50 or city = 'new york'
```

The result of that operation would be a subset of the original XML only with the records that match the conditions in the query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something a bit similar called a [`RowSet`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sql/RowSet.html), which is part of the JDBC spec. You can get data and cache them in a [`CacheRowSet`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html) that you can manipulate or even update later. Seems like there is also a [`FilteredRowSet`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/FilteredRowSet.html), so that you can create view that shows only the data you want.

This looks relatively similar to ADO.NET `DataView` and `DataSet`. Note also that `RowSet` are  not popular in Javaland.

A few more pointers:

- A small introduction: http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/06/23/cachedrowset.html
- Early access reference implementation: http://java.sun.com/developer/earlyAccess/jdbc/jdbc-- rowset.html
- JDBC API and Implementations: http://java.sun.com/products/jdbc/download.html#rowset1_0_1

Comment: Yes, I came across that interface, but found no concrete implementations of it...

Comment: I've added links to the reference implementation

Comment: The last link may solve my problem. I will try it out - and then accept the answer. I was just thinking if there would be anything else... Thanks!

Comment: It seems those are the only options I have... I agree with you, it seems that RowSet is really not popular in Javaland. I may end up with something else.